# Returning rows after combining table data

Tags: mysql

So I have a table that is a reference table and it has the following columns

```
(id, profileID, resourceID)
sample rows
(1, 1, 22)
(2, 1, 23)
(3, 22, 75)
```

The `id` is a primary key, the `resourceID` refers to the `resourceID` in the Resource table

Resource Table Columns:

```
(id, path)
sample rows
(22,'user/sam.jpg')
(23,'user/ann.jpg')
(75,'user/tom.jpg')
```

I need to query reference table first, then resource table. I would like to know what resources belong to profileID = 1 and I am expecting the following result:

```
(22,'user/sam.jpg')
(23,'user/ann.jpg')
```

Please forgive me as this is my first time to post in this forum and I am promise to learn formatting better in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a join and where clause to filter data set for profileID = 1

```
select a.*,b.path
from reference a
join resource b on a.resourceID = b.id
where a.profileID = 1
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/992df/1)

Comment: This works perfectly, and I am already learning more from this example. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Use join with where**

```
select resource.id, resource.path from RESOURCE resource INNER JOIN REFERENCE_TABLE ref_table
resource.id=ref_table.resourceID
where ref_table.profile_id=1
```